# Can a succeeded saving throw against the Horryfing Visage from one banshee make the player immune against the Horryfing Visage from another?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

If the players are facing two banshees and a player succeeds in the saving throw against one's Horrifying Visage, is he immune to the Horrifying Visage from another one?

Comment: Related: "[How do multiple ghast stench fields work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/138896)"